# Minimum amount of Tritium for fusion reaction producing Tritium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fusion

I'm not studying physics. I only worked with basic dynamics and have no idea how to calculate this. It's likely that the answer to the question I'm asking is nonsensical, but, from my point of view, it's still worth asking, since I have no idea if that's the case:

- How can I find out if there's a minimum to how many Tritium atoms are
  needed in oder to start a Deuterium-Tritium fusion reaction that's
  able to be used to make more Tritium out of liquid Lithium keeping
  the reaction going?

The question isn't about the concept of a specific test reactor. I don't know which parameters regarding the reactor would be important for an answer. I don't care about any of them as long as they sound realistic to you.

I don't expect anybody to write a complex explanation. Maybe you can help me by editing the question in a way it makes more sense to you. Thanks.

Comment: Well, clearly you need one tritium before you can have any fusion with deuterium. Then the question is whether you can actually get that one neutron produced by D-T to make another tritium, and that is a question of cross sections and reactor design (and, no, you will never have 100% success).

Comment: Reposting a closed question is not the right thing to do.

Comment: @JonCuster If a question got changed, we shouldn't call it a 'repost'. I didn't think anybody would want to close it for the same reason my first question got closed. Closing a question without allowing me to edit also isn't that great.

Comment: You can edit your closed questions.

Comment: @JonCuster nope. not this one

Comment: Ah, I see that the migration from Worldbuilding was rejected, so you can go edit it there.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I find out if there's a minimum to how many Tritium atoms are
> needed in oder to start a Deuterium-Tritium fusion reaction that's
> able to be used to make more Tritium out of liquid Lithium keeping the
> reaction going?

A simple answer is that ITER will burn [about 18 kg](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S092037961830379X) over its lifetime. Now that doesn't tell you what the startup load is, because that's entirely variable - there's no critical mass in a fusion design, you can run it at 1/1000th fuel load and it will still work while requiring 1/1000th the T it would at a "full" load.

But if one considers a ~15 year mainline experimental cycle (assuming 2035 through 2050 when a DEMO would come online) then we're talking about something on the order of 1 kg a year for a reactor running in production, which I think is what you're really getting at.

This is a problem, because the most common source of [civilian tritium at this point is the CANDU fleet](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S092037961830379X), which is slowly being dismembered, and those stocks they do have radiate away with every year ITER is delayed. CANDU is replacing these stocks at the rather low rate of about 130 grams per year, and a single reactor would burn around 1 kg a year, so this is **not** a trivial problem.

Sustained use of a reactor, therefore, demands breeding. So then we have to consider how much tritium can we expect to produce from a D-T fusion reactor?

Depending on who you ask, the number is somewhere between 1.1 T per fusion and 1.8. So at first glance, a fusion reactor can be self-sustaining in terms of T, and even produce enough to feed into other reactors. We would be able to bootstrap a new reactor every 3 or 4 years, which is not a very good number if you want to have fusion make up any realistic part of the energy mix.

**However**, there are various loss mechanisms throughout the chain. Neutrons can be lost in the first wall or leave the reactor entirely, they may drop below the threshold needed for breeding, etc. Additionally, there are any number of loss mechanisms in post-reactor processing, we may not be able to extract the T efficiently from the blanket (recall that we've never actually attempted this yet!), T is leaky on its own, and its decaying too.

This is a major unsolved problem.

**Update:**

I looked up [the numbers for DEMO](https://www.iter.org/mach/TritiumBreeding). 300 g **per day**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You were very helpful